# I increased VM storage from Virtual Media Manager in VBox but it is not applied in VM

Tags: partition, virtualbox, disk-usage, storage

Here is how I increased the storage of the VM in the VBox interface:
[image: storage attributes in GUI for root partition]

I used Virtual Media Manager.
When I click Information:

- Format: VDI
- Storage details: Dynamically allocated

Using the suggestion, I also used the command to increase it but no!

```
 root  pop-os  ../VirtualBox VMs/Kali  VBoxManage modifyhd Kali.vdi --resize 35000
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
```

As you see, it should be 31.52GB but let's go to VM and run

```
┌──(root㉿kali)-[~]
└─# df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            666M     0  666M   0% /dev
tmpfs           141M  926k  140M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        18G   17G  120M 100% /
tmpfs           705M     0  705M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           141M   82k  141M   1% /run/user/0
```

It is affecting the partitioning because I am not able to see the increase.

```
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    0   18G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   17G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0  975M  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

is again showing 18GB, not 32 GB.

Strangely also look :

```
 root  pop-os  ../VirtualBox VMs/Kali  du -sh *
12K Kali.vbox
12K Kali.vbox-prev
17G Kali.vdi
616K    Logs
13G Snapshots
```

[image: GParted]

Comment: @wodikiy313 do you have snapshots of the vm? If you do, then it seems you need to remove them. Check [this](https://superuser.com/a/688980).

Comment: @EdgarMagallon YOU ARE **** LIFESAVER! Finally after all research. Thank you, I removed screenshots, used GParted and finally got my space!

Comment: @EdgarMagallon could you please post the solution as an answer so the question can be marked as answered?

Comment: @terdon sure! I'll do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing VM storage might fail if you have snapshots of your VM.

In this [virtualbox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=46979) they mention this:

> Note also that the resize command cannot enlarge a drive that includes snapshots.

So you will have to remove them (or move to another directory) in order to be able to resize your VM correctly.